# Gson mapping to pojo returns null when running release variant with proguad enabled, even with @SerializedName added

Tags: java, android, json, android-proguard

**Please note that some might suggest i add the model class to the proguard -keep, i emphasize that i don't want to do that, due to security restriction guidelines imposed by my employer, i'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve editing proguard rules**

Using Gson to parse the a Json formatted string into an array mapped to a Pojo, everything works fine is debug variant
but when in release build with proguard enabled, the properties of the mapped Pojo objects return null causing the application to crash, below is the model/pojo class:

```
package com.xx.xxxxxxx


import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BeneficiaryModel implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("beneficiaryId")
    @Expose
    private String beneficiaryId;

    @SerializedName("beneficiaryName")
    @Expose
    private String beneficiaryName;

    @SerializedName("beneficiaryType")
    @Expose
    private String beneficiaryType;

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;


    public String getBeneficiaryId() {
        return beneficiaryId;
    }


    public void setBeneficiaryId(String beneficiaryId) {
        this.beneficiaryId = beneficiaryId;
    }


    public String getBeneficiaryName() {
        return beneficiaryName;
    }


    public void setBeneficiaryName(String beneficiaryName) {
        this.beneficiaryName = beneficiaryName;
    }


    public String getBeneficiaryType() {
        return beneficiaryType;
    }


    public void setBeneficiaryType(String beneficiaryType) {
        this.beneficiaryType = beneficiaryType;
    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

and this is how i serilaize the json string to array of objects

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
clientes = gson.fromJson(beneficiaryStringJsonArray, BeneficiaryModel[].class);
models =  new ArrayList<BeneficiaryModel>(Arrays.asList(clientes));

Log.e("TAG", models.get(0).getBeneficiaryId() + "," +  models.get(0).getBeneficiaryName());
// Log returns  null , null
```

Here's the portion of the Json string response needs to be serialized:

```
[{"beneficiaryId":"XYZ54646464646","beneficiaryName":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1","beneficiaryType":"","status":"ACTIVE"},{"beneficiaryId":"XYZ5468524654","beneficiaryName":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx2","beneficiaryType":"","status":"ACTIVE"}]
```

( as i mentioned before everything works fine in debug mode )

Comment: Have you taken a look at the gson proguard? https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg I know it says to keep the models, but try it without that part. Also, could you post an example of the Json?

Comment: Can you post the data from `beneficiaryStringJsonArray`?

Comment: Unfortunately @Fred i can't add the model to -keep in proguard due to development guideline restrictions by my employer, i tried adding the other rules though without adding models and still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i found that worked for me was using jackson library, i only had to add a few rules to my proguard without adding the models or any other files in my app.
here's the rules you'll need for jackson

```
# Proguard configuration for Jackson 2.x
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}

-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

Of course i'm still open to suggestion regarding how to solve issue using Gson, appreciate any suggestions